# ios app rejected on using AWS cognito implementation from mobile hub

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

We recently got our ios app rejected because of the following:

> We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for an account, which provides a poor user experience.

however, the bit that launches the safari window for facebook/Google login is part of the AWSMobileHubHelper framework so we can't modify that code.

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a workaround.  I just grab the GIDSignIn instance and change the properties myself.  In case any one else wants to know how, all you have to do is:

1. Add a bridge header and import `#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>`
2. Implement the presentViewController method for GIDSignInUIDelegate on your main login controller

```
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

3. Edit demo login code to be something like this:

```
     func loginWithGoogle(delegate: GIDSignInUIDelegate!) {
            let googleProvider = AWSGoogleSignInProvider.sharedInstance()

            // It is important that these are initialized after 
            // AWSGoogleSignInProvider.sharedInstance() is called
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = delegate
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = false
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = true

            handleLoginWithSignInProvider(googleProvider, callback: callback)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Did this work with aws mobile hub application? from what I have gathered, they reset this value in AWSGoogleSignInProvider.m not just for initial signin, but also for resuming session.

Comment: From what I could tell, it worked for me in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 9 using Facebook SDK, this is expected behavior per Facebook login. Mobile Hub quickstart app is just applying the Facebook SDK 3 and using the APIs as directed. Check out the brief description below and read through the comments to get a better insight. This was not a popular decision by Facebook and others have provided workarounds (to forcing user authentication via mobile browser) if you wish to experiment. As for the AWSMobileHubHelper framework, we are looking into making this available at some point but don't have a timeline for this.

"Logic that automatically defaults people to the optimum experience for iOS 9. This means that the SDK dialogs for Facebook Login, Sharing across Facebook and Messenger, App Invites, App Events, or Native Like will automatically determine the best experience for people based on their device."

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/09/10/new-SDK-for-iOS9/

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the question is not about Facebook SDK 3 alone. It's about the default behavior for facebook/Google login that AWSMobileHubHelper provides. Google SDK 3 (that comes bundled with mobilehub) provides methods to launch login pages in web view (via allowsSignInWithWebView), but the AWS helper chooses to launch in Safari instead by setting allowsSignInWithBrowser to true. Needless to say, if built in functionality of AWSMobileHub causes your app to be rejected in app store... then it's a problem...